# No sound when PulseAudio is running

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, alsa, pulseaudio

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 running the latest Raspbian jessie. I have sound working just fine via ALSA and analog out. Recently I installed pulseaudio and have found if pulseaudio is running I no longer have any sound. If I do a `killall pulseaudio` then I once again have sound (provided I restart the process which is attempting to output sound).

I have found that even with pulseaudio running, if an application is directly outputting to ALSA, then I still have sound (for example, if I tell Kodi to use ALSA, I get the menu sounds; if I tell it pulseaudio, I get nothing. If I start up the Pixel browser and go to youtube and watch a video, I get no sound if PulseAudio is running; however if I stop pulseaudio and restart the browser; boom.. I have sound.)

I am not sure where to look as I am a novice when it comes to linux, but I suspect that somehow my pulseaudio is misconfigured. Perhaps it is attempting to output via HDMI? I have my pi configured to force output via analog, but perhaps pulseaudio is not respecting that setting?